# simulate mouse click (pointerdown?) in js

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I created this fork of [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@silevis/reactgrid):

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactgrid-highlights-forked-shvr4z

I'm trying to write a test that selects a cell and edits it (jest).
I didn't see that they export their test utils.

So I tried to select the cell, with no success.
I downloaded their library, tried to debug their code and think they trigger pointerdown event when selecting a cell.

I tried to simulate it with:

```
const event = new PointerEvent('pointerdown')
myElement = document.querySelector('[data-cell-rowidx="1"][data-cell-colidx="0"]');
myElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Or other variations.

In addition, I tried with @testing-library/user-event:

```
userEvent.click(...)

pointer([
  {keys: '[MouseLeft>]', target: myElement},
  {keys: '[/MouseLeft]'},
])
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you simply try `myElement.click()` ?

Comment: Yes and it wasn't work.

Comment: @AlonShmiel "it didn't work"

Answer (score 1):

Succeeded!

```
const simulateMouseEvent = function(element, eventName, coordX, coordY) {
  element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(eventName, {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: coordX,
    clientY: coordY,
    button: 0
  }));
};

const theButton = document.querySelector('[data-cell-rowidx="1"][data-cell-colidx="0"]')

const box = theButton.getBoundingClientRect(),
        coordX = box.left + (box.right - box.left) / 2,
        coordY = box.top + (box.bottom - box.top) / 2;

simulateMouseEvent (theButton, "pointerdown", coordX, coordY);
simulateMouseEvent (theButton, "pointerup", coordX, coordY);
simulateMouseEvent (theButton, "click", coordX, coordY);
```